# Can't find css and javascript on spring maven project

Tags: javascript, css, spring, maven, netbeans

I have an application using spring framework using maven project. I also have an css and js under WEB-INF folder. When i try to call the javascript and css like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../allDesign/js/vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
```

I can open the url to open via project, but when i try to run, i get an error that the browser can't find the source code.

the error show like this :

[image]

Here our structure of my project:

[image]

can you tell me how to fix the url?, because when i try to click the url on netbeans, netbeans can find my animsition.min.css.

Comment: Is this project a spring project? If yes then please post your configuraion (the resource mapping is the interessting part)

Answer (score 0):

Files in the `WEB-INF` and `META-INF` folder are protected, you can not access them directly.

So move your `allDesign` as a direct subfolder of `Web Packages`.